# automatically generate tags from content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags

my WordPress website contents have some words in every line, 
I want a code to automatically convert every line in content to tag (every line not every word), let's say my content is like this:

```
Beagle puppy
Costumes
Wales
Dogs
```

I want tags from every line: Beagle puppy, Costumes, Wales, Dogs

I don't want to use plugins, because I used some but it needs a keyword list to match the content. I don't want to use any keyword list to match the content. 
is it possible to convert every line in content into one tag?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant what you appeared to mean - for instance, that the source post consists solely of the lines to be converted, the lines won't include additional odd/inappropriate chracters to be handled, and so on - the following will work. If you need to convert a section of a post or some other element defined in some other way, or attach the lines as tags to the current post, etc., then you'll need to provide those details clearly.

1. Place shortcode [convert_post_lines_to_tags] in new output post.
2. Save draft, and preview (shortcode won't function yet, obviously)
3. Add functions to your theme functions.php
4. Provide "$source_post_id" where indicated.
5. Re-load output post

```php
    add_shortcode( 'convert_post_lines_to_tags', 'convert_post_lines_to_tags' ) ;

    function convert_post_lines_to_tags() {

        $source_post_id = '' ; //Provide ID Number of post with lines to be converted

        $i = 0 ;
        $newTags = 'New tags inserted: <br />' ;

        //TIL - PHP requires double quotes to replace escaped characters
        $post_content = str_replace( 
            array( "\r\n", "\r" ), ',', get_post( $source_post_id )->post_content 
        ) ; 

        $post_line_array = explode( ',', $post_content ) ;

        foreach ( $post_line_array as $line_tag ) { 

            $tag = wp_insert_term( $line_tag, 'post_tag' ) ;

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $tag ) ) {

                $i++ ; 
                $newTags .= $i . '. ' . get_term( $tag['term_id'] )->name . '<br />' ;
            } 

        } 

        return $newTags ;

    }
```